# What is the proper way to create a vlan?

Tags: networking, hp, vlan, cisco-asa

My goal is to create a separate VLAN, that will be isolated from the rest of the office, I just want them to have internet.

Normal pc stations x1 HP Procurve switch V1910 x1 cisco asa 5512-x

What I've done so far without luck:

1. configured the VLAN on the HP Switch,
   Configured a port with that vlan id, tagged, hybrid port.

   - I've also configured VLAN interface on the switch assigned an ip address of that VLAN address.
2. on the ASA, I've created a sub interface with the same vlan ID, IP address on the same vlan subner, created an acl rule for incoming and created a dynamic pat NAT rule for the vlan subnet.
3. configured my laptop NIC with the vlan ID, configured manual IP of that vlan subnet.

What an I doing wrong? or should have done different?

Comment: How far have you come so far, and what doesn't work?

Comment: I followed so many different guides.. nothing actually worked. I created the vlan on the HP switch. changed the port to hybrid and marked it as tagged, I created a sub-interface on the ASA with the same VLAN ID, ACL+NAT was created for that new interface and subnet, but no go.. I tried it with a laptop which is vlan aware, with or without a vlan id configured, it didn't work.

Comment: You need to flesh out the question with hard info about all that, make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the port on the HP switch to untagged for that VLAN.
2. Assuming you are using the same HP switch to connect to the ASA, set the VLAN to tagged on the port connecting to your ASA
3. Don't tag traffic on the endpoint.